# Javascript: Error while converting Unicode string to hex

Tags: javascript, unicode, hex, sapui5

I'm trying to convert a unicode string to a hexadecimal representation in javascript controller in SAPUI5 WebIDE.

I am using this function to convert the unicode data to hex. Str variable contains the Unicode data

```
convertToHex: function(str) {

        var hex = '';
        var i = 0;
        while (str.length > i) {
            hex += '' + str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
            i++;
        }
        console.log(hex);
        return hex;
    },
```

This is first line of the result i am getting in hex variable

```
504b3414060800021062ee9d685e10090400130825b436f6e74656e745f54797065735d2e786d6c20a24228a002
```

Now when i am uploading same data to SAP Netweaver gateway, it converts the unicode data to hex as follows (First line) :

```
504B03041400060008000000210062EE9D685E01000090040000130008025B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20A2040228A00002
```

This is the decoded unicode:

```
PK!bîh^[Content_Types].xml ¢(
```

For my application to work i need both hex codes to be same but i am not able to generate the correct hex code in Javascript whereas in SAP i am getting the correct hex values.

Comment: What is the incoming string for provided hex codes above?

Comment: @Skay "PK!bîh^[Content_Types].xml ¢(" is the unicode string for both the Hex codes